# "Registrator", "registrar", or "registry" when describing the responsibility of managing registration-related activities

Tags: word-choice, programming

When naming a class in an object-oriented programming language I came a across [a case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864527/naming-of-domain-objects-that-act-like-ddd-building-blocks-such-as-repositories/5868372#5868372) where there were a few proposed names for describing a component that is responsible for abstracting registration related actions.

Candidate names:

> - ApplicationRegistrator
> - ApplicationRegistrar
> - ApplicationRegistry

Which of these phrases more properly describes the scenario?

Comment: This question would probably better suit http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No not at all, it has nothing to do with programming itself. They would've slashed it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno No, bikeshedding class names is not welcome on Programmers.SE.

Comment: That's fine, but it is not on-topic here too, IMO. It would be like asking why CakePHP is called so.

Answer (score 12):

In ordinary English (outside the IT world), a "registrar" is a person who performs some sort of registration, and a "registry" is an office in which registration happens, or a store in which registrations are recorded. (In the University of Cambridge, there is a "registrary", who is a person; but I don't believe that is used anywhere else).

I have never encountered "registrator" (but the OED lists it)

So I would favour "registrar". "Registry" would be a possible alternative, but I would use that for where the registrations are held, rather than for the agent which performs them.

Answer (score 8):

I would not use *registrator*, as its non-programming use is rare and ambiguous, and there are other common words which are clearer.

Try this: a couple wish to have their marriage *registered*.  They go as *registrants* to the *registry* where the *registrar* enters their names and the date in the *register* of marriages.

Answer (score 3):

If your class is actually storing the data, it's a `Registry`.

If your class is responsible for putting the data into a different storage, it's a `Registrator`.

If it's doing both, it's a `Registrar`. They record data and keep the records too.

Comment: Interesting, are the applications of these words comming from a particular dictionary? I like the clean subdivisions of use but I'm wondering whether this is something that the majority of English speakers would pick up on.

Comment: I used Google to "define: <whatever>" - seems consistent across multiple dictionaries. Also matches the connotations I feel; registrars keep records of marriages, but a registrator seems more action-oriented than state-oriented. Maybe most English speakers wouldn't notice if you mix up Registrar / Registrator, so my StackOverflow or Programmers.SE answer would be to ask the team.

Answer (score 2):

- Registrator -> Person or device which records data
- Registry -> Generally refers to the book/document contaning the records themselves. (eg.: Windows registry)
- Registrar -> One who administers the registry.

From your description of the component, it seems, the component is likely to manage the registry (i.e. conduct operations upon them) therefore **registrar**, to me, seems appropriate.

Another example of such usage of registrar: [Registrar of companies](http://www.mca.gov.in/Ministry/roc.html), the office responsible for maintaining the register of companies registered.